# Background selector not working in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Hello I am using lazycolumn inside column to show my nested list. When I am trying to click on single item, it's clicking on whole another items as well instead of single and color is not changing as well.

```
 binding.itemComposable.setContent {
     val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
     val isPressed by interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
     val backgroundColor = if (isPressed) DuckEggBlue else OffWhite
     val clickable = Modifier.clickable(
         interactionSource = interactionSource,
         indication = LocalIndication.current
     ) {
         println("Item Click")
     }
     Column(
         modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxSize(),
         verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
     ) {
         val options = getOptions()
         options.forEachIndexed { _, optionText ->
             Card(
                 shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                 modifier = Modifier.then(clickable)
             ) {
                 Text(
                     modifier = Modifier
                         .fillMaxWidth()
                         .background(backgroundColor)
                         .padding(16.dp),
                     text = optionText,
                     style = Typography.h3,
                     fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                     color = Slate
                 )
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

You can check in the [video](https://youtube.com/shorts/Mxf8ZDvJ54Y?feature=share)

1. All items are selecting instead of single
2. When selecting item background color is not changing according to my DuckEggBlue color.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the state of `isPressed` is outside of your `.forEachIndexed` loop, the single instance of the state is shared between every row. If you would like each row to have its own instance state, simply move that block into the loop.

[image]

Comment: What about color change ?

Comment: @vivekmodi Check the definition of your colors, because I am not seeing a code problem with that part. To test, I changed the colors to be more drastic `val backgroundColor = if (isPressed) Color.Blue else Color.Green` and see that it's working fine.